# Easy way to convert xmlElements XML

Tags: actionscript-3, sdk, adobe-indesign

I'm making an extension for indesign in flex. I need to convert xmlElements to xml. When you export a file as xml, you get a nicely structured xml file. But how can i easily convert exmlElements to use in my code?

Comment: And the question of the hour is. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call exportFile from a xmlElement. Once that said, you should be able to get a nicely xml structure.

Here is a simple test :

```
app.activeDocument.xmlElements[0].xmlElements[-1].exportFile ( ExportFormat.XML , File ( Folder.desktop + "/test.xml" ) );
```

Then the output gives me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Article>dssds</Article>
```

Loic